# is it safe to use cpp libraries installed by conda in one executable on linux?

Tags: c++, conda, conda-forge

conda forge can be used to install many cpp libraries like gperftools, flatbuffers, parquet, boost etc.

my understanding is that using cpp libraries compiled by different compiler or different version of compiler could cause issues due to API compatibility. as what is described in  [Using shared libraries and mismatched compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641751/using-shared-libraries-and-mismatched-compilers)

so it may not be safe to use cpp libraries installed by conda forge, as they may be compiled by different compilers.  but I've been doing this for a long time and everything works fine.

I am wondering if there is a guideline about this. has condon forge somehow make sure all cpp libraries are compatible? or they don't guanteen this at all. it's just lucky that I haven't run into any problems yet?

---

thanks flyingTeller for posting the link, it seems that conda forge will upgrade compiling tools when they have time to do so, and build everything using the upgraded compiling tools. so all libraries downloaded after an uprade should be ok to use.
but if some libraries are downloaded before an upgrade and some are not, there could be problems. so basically, if there is an upgrade, either update everything or do nothing.

this is the conclusion I draw. not sure if it's correct or not though.

Comment: I don't know the tool, but if it is built by sensible people then it will only pull down artifacts compiled with the same compiler as what you have locally (and same build options). The `conan` package manager does this, for example.

Comment: Are you looking for https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/infrastructure.html#compilers-and-runtimes ?

Comment: Do you mean ABI? This is mostly coordinated through [global pinning](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock). The pinned versions used during compilation get injected into the metadata, and, when done properly, only allow compatible versions to co-install. The thing Conda Forge cannot guarantee is behavior when channel mixing.